# SQL SELECT not returning value

Tags: sql, select, casting

I have the following query in SQL:

```
SELECT idPass
FROM Notes
WHERE CAST(CreatedDate AS nvarchar) LIKE '2016-07-30 17:19:10%'
AND CreatedBy='César Caldeira - CEC'
AND idUser='7'
```

I'm a noob with SQL; this has no syntax errors but I don't know how to make it work?

Any advice?

This is my table structure:

```
idPass int
CreatedDate datetime
CreatedBy nvarchar(50)
idUser int
```

The problem is datetime has the format `yyyy-mm-ss.mmm` and I don't have access to the last 3 digits of the date so I can't use `CreatedDate = somedate`

Comment: Please format SQL to make more readable - I will edit

Comment: We would need to see some data and a definition of the columns (i.e. data types, lengths, etc.) in order to help.  As you say, the syntax is correct, so it has to be related to data.

Comment: Well what does your data look like? Maybe there is no match

Comment: remove your where clauses.... start with
WHERE idUser='7'  as example..

This way you will see where the error is

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using; also, explain what "not working" means.

Comment: What do you mean, that you don't have _access_ to the last 3 digits of a value of a column? :o

Comment: @KamilG. The date is being sent from client without them...

Comment: what rdbms, sql-server? mysql? oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sql-server answer that will strip off the milliseconds (last 3 digits) and compare as dates.

```
SELECT idPass
FROM Notes
WHERE DATEADD(ms,- DATEPART(ms,CreatedDate),CreatedDate) = CAST('2016-07-30 17:19:10' AS DATETIME)
AND CreatedBy='César Caldeira - CEC'
AND idUser='7'
```

Here is a SQL Server 2012+ answer that uses FORMAT to drop off milliseconds and compare as strings.

```
SELECT idPass
FROM Notes
WHERE FORMAT(CreatedDate ,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') = '2016-07-30 17:19:10'
AND CreatedBy='César Caldeira - CEC'
AND idUser='7'
```

Comment: SQL Server 2012 answer works just fine! Thanks I'm starting my life in SQL and don't know the possibilities yet!

Comment: your welcome, If you get into huge datasets you may need the date one or using a similar method for performance but that will be a different question at that point. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Sql Server,

```
SELECT idPass
FROM Notes
where CAST(CreatedDate as date) = '2016-07-30' 
    and DATEPART( hh, CreatedDate) = 17 
    and DATEPART( mi, CreatedDate) = 19 
    and DATEPART( ss, CreatedDate) = 10
AND CreatedBy='César Caldeira - CEC'
AND idUser='7'
```

Answer (score 0):

### MySQL

Use `date_format()` function to get rid of miliseconds part:

```
DATE_FORMAT(CreatedDate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

So your query would now look:

```
SELECT idPass
FROM Notes
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(CreatedDate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') = '2016-07-30 17:19:10'
  AND CreatedBy = 'César Caldeira - CEC'
  AND idUser = 7
```

### SQL Server

Using a trick within `dateadd()` to omit miliseconds by substracting them:

```
DATEADD(ms, -DATEPART(ms, CreatedDate), CreatedDate)
```

So your query would now look:

```
SELECT idPass
FROM Notes
WHERE DATEADD(ms, -DATEPART(ms, CreatedDate), CreatedDate) = '2016-07-30 17:19:10'
  AND CreatedBy = 'César Caldeira - CEC'
  AND idUser = 7
```

*Additional note:*

- You don't need to use inverted commas around `Integer` values (idUser)